# Visuallizing a set of states in real time

Tags: gazebo, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to stimulate in 2D a simple robot, and I want to visualize a portion of the state space (the set of inevitable collision states for instance) that changes in real time.

I am using Gazebo as a simulator, and the state space is a simple grid (a regular lattice).

How could this be nicely done using Gazebo or Rviz?

Thanks in advance!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/104896/visuallizing-a-set-of-states-in-real-time./) by [mowahed](https://answers.ros.org/users/4645/mowahed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2013-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[rviz](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz) has several visualization plugins to which you can publish data and visualize this sort of thing.  Here's a [list of display types](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes) I'd suggest looking at publishing Gridcells or Markers.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amine23](https://answers.ros.org/users/3879/amine23/) on 2013-11-27**:
Thanks, l'll look into them.